# Rebuilding Remix project fails to kill process 26104 (Microsoft Edge)

Tags: node.js, node-modules, remix, remix.run

I'm going through the short tutorial on Remix website. Every time I save my project, it fails to rebuild because it can't find a certain task. I looked at the task manager and that process is Microsoft Edge. Not sure why it's trying to kill it!

```
  remix dev

 info  building...
 info  built (8s)

> dev:serve
> binode --require ./mocks -- @remix-run/serve:remix-serve ./build

 Mock server running
Remix App Server started at http://localhost:3000 (http://10.0.0.128:3000)

GET /posts 200 - - 30.086 ms
 info  rebuilding... (~ app\routes\posts._index.tsx)
 info  rebuilt (391ms)

C:\Projects\blog-tutorial\node_modules\@remix-run\dev\dist\devServer_unstable\proc.js:29
    throw new Error(`Failed to kill process ${pid}: ${error}`);
          ^

Error: Failed to kill process 26104: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: taskkill /F /PID 26104
ERROR: The process with PID 26104 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
    at kill (C:\Projects\blog-tutorial\node_modules\@remix-run\dev\dist\devServer_unstable\proc.js:29:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at async Object.killtree (C:\Projects\blog-tutorial\node_modules\@remix-run\dev\dist\devServer_unstable\proc.js:43:3)
    at async onBuildFinish (C:\Projects\blog-tutorial\node_modules\@remix-run\dev\dist\devServer_unstable\index.js:236:13)

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Comment: It’s a known issue that is fixed in the next release. https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/6768

Comment: I used this https://github.com/brophdawg11/upgrade-remix to upgrade and then `npm install`.

Comment: “Next” release as in v1.18.2. You can try the nightly release if you need.